# Hibernate Generation Class

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, generator

I am using a hibernate application to store data in Postgres database I have created HBM file from POJO. The table consist of ID which is `bigserial` identically it should be autogenerated. but when i run project after insertion of a record it doesnt increament value of id hence throws exception:

```
 SEVERE: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "usertable_pkey"
 SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
 org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

My HBM entry is as follows:

```
<id name="userid" type="long">
        <column name="userid" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

Can anyone suggest which generator class I can use to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting transactional data it is prefered to use a`[sequence][2]` to generate the id if the object.

```
<id ....>
        <generator class="sequence">
           <param name="sequence">YOUR_SEQUENCE _NAME</param>
       </generator>
</id>
```

this will ensure that even in multi-threaded environments you will get different id for different objects.

Read the API about generator classes [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id).